# Why doesn't this code using the ruby-mbox gem parse mbox files?

Tags: ruby, email, rubygems, mbox

I installed ruby-mbox by doing **gem install ruby-mbox**

Running this:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'mbox'
m = IO.read('test.eml')
puts m.size
m = Mbox.new(m)
puts m
```

produces this exception (at line 7):

**/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/ruby-mbox-0.0.2/lib/mbox/mbox.rb:45:in `initialize': uninitialized constant Mbox::StringIO (NameError)**

I have proved that "m" is assigned a string containing the contents of the file, just before Mbox.new(m) is called.

It looks as though the **Mbox::StringIO** should have been defined by hasn't been.

**What's going wrong here?**

Ruby version:

```
ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [universal-darwin10.0]
```

(That's the default ruby installed on OS X 10.6.6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry people, I should have looked harder before posting here...

Fixed it:

Just inserted the line **require 'stringio'** to give this:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'stringio'
require 'mbox'
m = IO.read('test.eml')
puts m.size
m = Mbox.new(m)
puts m
```

It looks like stringio is assumed to be loaded - but isn't loaded explicitly by ruby-mbox...

Oddly, the example scripts don't load it either...